# mySQL Crashing with InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread in file sync0rw.c line 572

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, innodb

Uploading a 30 meg file into a longblob column via JDBC is crashing mysql with the following error.  I can't find anything on google.  Any help will be much appreciated

131115 15:34:13  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 1669131072 in file sync0rw.c line 572

Here is how I am doing this via JDBC:

```
public static void setObjectInstBlobOpenCon(String objInstId, InputStream is, long size, String fieldNm, Connection conn) throws SQLException  {

    try {
        String typeTable = getObjectInstanceTypeTbl(objInstId);


        PreparedStatement  cStmt = conn.prepareStatement("update " + typeTable + " " + 
                                                    "set " + fieldNm + " = ? " + 
                                                    "where object_ky = ?"  
                                                    );

        if (size == 0) {
            cStmt.setBinaryStream(1, is);
        } else {
            cStmt.setBinaryStream(1, is, size);
        }

        cStmt.setString(2, objInstId);          

        cStmt.execute();

        //conn.close();

    } catch(SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Mysql Statement Error:  call setObjectInstBlob(?) for object " + objInstId );
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The full error is:

```
131115 15:34:13  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 1669131072 in file sync0rw.c line 572
InnoDB: Failing assertion: !lock->recursive
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
15:34:13 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=29
max_threads=151
thread_count=25
connection_count=25
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346075 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0xffffffffbac68c40
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 637ce2cc thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x33)[0xb726d9b3]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x484)[0xb7119f14]
[0xb6dcd400]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x58613f)[0xb737613f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5c22a0)[0xb73b22a0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5c58a4)[0xb73b58a4]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5771f6)[0xb73671f6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x531fc8)[0xb7321fc8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x53590a)[0xb732590a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x536529)[0xb7326529]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x520bfd)[0xb7310bfd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x50d546)[0xb72fd546]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN7handler13ha_update_rowEPKhPh+0x7a)[0xb712290a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_updateP3THDP10TABLE_LISTR4ListI4ItemES6_PS4_jP8st_ordery15enum_duplicatesbPySB_+0x154d)[0xb706952d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0xf42)[0xb6fdfbf2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0xfc)[0xb6fe7e1c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0x2362)[0xb6fea252]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0xd3)[0xb6feac93]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x1eb)[0xb709eb9b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x50)[0xb709ec00]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/tls/i686/nosegneg/libpthread.so.0(+0x6d4c)[0xb6d49d4c]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/tls/i686/nosegneg/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e)[0xb6b58bae]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (5e24b018): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 501
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Edit: 2013-11-16

While this is not a solution, the workaround for me was to convert the table that was going to be hosting these large binary files to myIsam instead of InnoDB.

The table is a transcoding queue table that holds large video files, and their transcoded equivalents.

It's the only table in my schema that will be hosting these massive files, and so it was not a big deal to convert it to myISAM by first dropping the one foreign key constraint I had on it.

So far I am happy with this solution.  The rest of my schema still benefits from the goodness innodb provides.